React - Sanity data query from different schemas
I am making a portfolio website that has a grid in the homepage to showcase 3 different categories of projects. I have 3 different schemas in sanity, each one with its own fields. Anyone knows what is the best way to query the data to create the grid - i am using react with vite. I tried some chatgpt suggestions together with youtube tutorials but I am not getting anything back.
I am a beginner so any help is very much appreciated. Thank you:))
This is the chatgpt suggestion

Should post code as text in a code block vice an image to make it easier to review.
